# Does SAP ABAP offer a way to sign assemblies?

Tags: binary, abap, sign, integrity, sap-basis

I'm trying to find out whether it is possible to sign binaries written for SAP systems in ABAP. Contextually does it make sense? I've only found some reference to an add-on assembly kit which seems to be some sort of packaging standard. Can this be used to authenticate the source and integrity of ABAP modules?

Greatly appreciate your feedback~!

I seem to have found an answer to my question somewhat...one forum discussion states that ABAP is only interpreted and that there are no binaries to sign in the first place. I'm a bit confused though as to what the Add-on Assembly Kit is. I suppose it's a way of packaging the ABAP code into a certifiable package, which I suppose is the closest we'll get to what I'm looking for-although I'm not sure how this works if you're not interested in sharing the package with SAP for certification...If you have any insights please enlighten me.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to sign $stuff in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not positive of your end requirement but I'll answer the best I can. ABAP is interpreted so there really is no need to sign a binary as there is none to sign. Because third party's needed ways to deliver solutions or code to their customers in a packaged manner SAP developed the add-on assembly toolkit, (emphasis on assembly) this allows the third party a tool to package all the solution pieces,( classes, tables, includes, screens etc.) into an add-on that can be installed, versioned etc. in your customers SAP system. So it's main purpose is to allow you to assemble the myriad pieces that make up your solution.

Of course if your talking about a single app, report etc. this obviously would be overkill.

If what you are seeking is a way to know that an app comes from your specific company, then you can request a custom namespace, when you get one assigned they issue you a key which only your company uses to install the namespace and that sort of works like signing,  your programs will all exist in your namespace and be identified as such.

I'm sure there are more details others can provide but that should get you started.

Later.....

Comment: Thanks SAPPRO, yes, the main point is really to ensure the authenticity/integrity of a running piece of code within an SAP environment. Thanks for your input!